# Permission set in AWS

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-iam, aws-security-group

I have one group in AWS as Incident-Security-operation, this group has only read-only permission to all the AWS account. But I want to give full permission or administrator to one account and read-only permission and to the rest of the accounts. Can you please help me to write permission with the condition for the particular account. I tried ArnLike and ArnEqual but didn't work for me. We integrated with AD for SSO

Comment: Why don't you just create another group and assign that user to both groups?

Comment: that is the easy option but can we use the same permission set and change it to only one group

Comment: Sorry, but your question is difficult to understand. Are you referring to an IAM Group?And what do you mean by "account" -- are you managing multiple AWS Accounts, or are you referring to IAM Users? What do you mean by "didn't work for me" -- can you show us what you tried, and what errors you received? Feel free to edit your question to clarify what you are wanting to do.

Answer (score 0):

Regard IAM users and group, best practice for this use case is to implement **two** IAM groups eg `Incident-Security-operation` and `Incident-Security-operation-admin`, and give permissions to each as needed. Then you assign users to each group as needed.

This approach fosters much better security posture than conditioning permissions in a single policy.

From an operational standpoint, its much easier, and more transparent, to move users between the appropriate IAM groups, than to manage conditional logic in the policy syntax. Using IAM groups also means user membership in each group is easily auditable.

Comment: Ah good choice I think. Kindly accept and up vote if you find it useful

Comment: I  want to create 2 groups and assign permissions set for the Incident responder group and Forensic group.

Full admin permission set for the AWS forensic account (forensic group)
Incident responder permission set for the rest of the AWS account.
I want to give full admin access to the forensic account. I don't know what permission set required the Incident responder group. Assume if EC2 or RDS, KMS or EBS or any other services in AWS have an incident and they need to create a snapshot and move the snapshot in the forensic account. Can you please guide me